# rpi python tcp server, swiftsocket ios client receiving only -1 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, raspberry-pi

I configure raspberry pi as tcp server that waits for connection gets the data and then send it back. On swift I copy and paste the example client code in readme file of swiftsocket. The connection is established raspberry receives the data send but ios only shows -1 in xcode terminal. The code I used in swift is:

```
let client = TCPClient(address: "192.168.0.50", port: 8080)
switch client.connect(timeout: 1) {
  case .success:
    switch client.send(string: "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" ) {
      case .success:
        guard let data = client.read(1024*10) else { return }

        if let response = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
          print(response)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
  case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Code formatting fixed

Comment: If you get -1 on the debug console, then your TCP server is sending "-1" as a response. Better check your server side code.